# Need Azure Search Lucene Query to Search the Records with following Scenario

Tags: azure, lucene, full-text-search, lucene.net, azure-cognitive-search

I have Azure search Index which has column as ProductName.

I have to show the ProductName based on how user searchs. So How Can I form the query if I want to search in between word.

**ProductName**

1. Microsoft Visual Studio 32bit
2. Microsoft Visual Basic Editor
3. Microsoft SQL Server
4. SQL Server Management Studio
5. Visual Studio Code

My requirements are -

If User searches **"SQL"** then User should get results like

1. SQL Server Management Studio
2. Microsoft SQL Server

**Solution -**

For this Scenario, I am calling my Azure Search Index as and **it works** 
https://myindex.search.windows.net/indexes/myproducts/docs?api-version=2017-11-11&search=/.*SQL.*/&queryType=full&$select=ProductName

==============================================

Second Scenario - If User searches **"Microsoft Vis"**
User should get two results

1. Microsoft Visual Studio 32bit
2. Microsoft Visual Basic Editor

How Can I get this Result? 
How to create a Query. I already search for My First Scenario But For my second scenario, I am stuck. Please help.

If I search Like this 
https://myindex.search.windows.net/indexes/myproducts/docs?api-version=2017-11-11&search=SQL*&searchMode=all&%24select=productName

==============================================================

**Third Scenario -** If User search for "soft" I need to show these results

1. Microsoft Visual Studio 32bit
2. Microsoft Visual Basic Editor
3. Microsoft SQL Server

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may try to call the following request url while searching "SQL"

```
https://myindex.search.windows.net/indexes/myproducts/docs?api-version=2017-11-11&search=SQL*&searchMode=all&%24select=productName
```

Or call this request url while searching "Microsoft Vis"

```
https://myindex.search.windows.net/indexes/myproducts/docs?api-version=2017-11-11&search=Microsoft%20Vis*&searchMode=all&%24select=productName
```

If you type 'Microsoft Visual B', you could call the following api:

```
https://myindex.search.windows.net/indexes/myproducts/docs?api-version=2017-11-11&search=Microsoft%20Visual%20B*&searchMode=all&%24select=productName
```

Comment: Thanks @Andy - I got it. 
But If I search with **"Microsoft Visual B"** then also I am getting two ProductNames. Ideally, It should return only one, **Microsoft Visual Basic Editor**

Comment: What is another ProductName you get ?

Comment: If I type "Microsoft Visual B" and calls search api
I am getting still getting both the Products **Microsoft Visual Studio 32bit**
and **Microsoft Visual Basic Editor**

Comment: You may have forgotten to append * to the end of "Microsoft Visual B".  You just change the search url param value to Microsoft%20Visual%20B*

Comment: -If I search like this 
`https://myindex.search.windows.net/indexes/myproducts/docs?api-version=2017-11-11&search=SQL*&querytype=full&searchmode=all` 
           

It returns following results 
`"value": [
        {
            "@search.score": 1,
            "ID": "46",
            "Name": "Microsoft SQL Server"
        },
        {
            "@search.score": 1,
            "ID": "47",
            "Name": "SQL Server Management Studio"
        },
        {
            "@search.score": 1,
            "ID": "51",
            "Name": "Microsoft SQL 32\\64"
        }
    ]`

Answer (score 0):

Azure Search breaks text when indexed into pieces called "tokens" that amount to the smallest segment of text you can search for.  An indexed word may result in multiple tokens depending on the analyzer selected for the field.

You should only need to provide a wildcard when you are you are looking for a token that begins with the text.  This is not the same as a starts with for the full string in the index.  In your examples, "SQL" would not need a wildcard.  "Vis*" needs the wildcard since you are looking for "visual".

Let me know if you have any additional questions.

Mike Carter
Azure Search product team

Comment: Thanks for comment. 
I have two requirements here. 
If User search for "soft" I need to show these results **1.Microsoft Visual Studio 32bit, 2. Microsoft Visual Basic Editor, 3.Microsoft SQL Server**

If User search for "Microsoft Vis" then it should show as per second scenario described in question.

Hence I calling Azure search like 

`https://myindex.search.windows.net/indexes/myproducts/docs?api-version=2017-11-11&search=Microsoft vis\* || /.*Microsoft vis.*/&queryType=full&searchMode=all`

In short I am taking searchTerm in one Variable and I am calling search api.